# React prop appears but then is undefined for function call?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I have a photo grid that I am building in React that is going to support photo upload. When the user clicks the upload button for a given photo, the upload button is supposed to execute the onChange function with text code coming from a prop named `imagecode`.

The onChange function is currently: `onChange={(event)=>console.log(props.imagecode)}`

I am using the React Chrome inspector and I can see that the imagecode prop is successfully defined on the component. However, when I try uploading a file, props.imagecode is `undefined`. What gives? Why is the prop appearing as `undefined`? I will need to do further logic upload photos with the imagecode identifier, but it appears to be a Shrodinger cat.

Here is my code:

```
const UploadButton = (props) =>{
    return (
        <div className="uploadPlusContainer" >
            <input className="imageUploadInput" type="file" onChange={(event)=>console.log(props.imagecode)} />
        </div>
    )
}

const Photo = (photoProps) =>{
    return(
        <div {...photoProps}>          
            <UploadButton {...photoProps}/>
        </div>
    )
}


const Photos = (props) =>{   

    return (
        <div className="flexColumn photoSection">
            <div className="flexRow">
                <Photo id="mainPhoto" className="secondaryPhoto" imagecode={"profile"}/>
                <div className="flexColumn">
                    <Photo key={0} className="secondaryPhoto"/>
                    <Photo key={1} className="secondaryPhoto"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flexRow">
                <Photo key={2} className="secondaryPhoto"/>
                <Photo key={3} className="secondaryPhoto"/>
                <Photo key={4} className="secondaryPhoto"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This works for me, although only the first Photo component has the imagecode prop passed in. None of the others ever receive it, so it makes sense that the bottom five buttons log undefined. (As an aside, you don't need to use {} if you just pass a raw string.)

Comment: The first photo (with id=mainPhoto), which is the one I’m testing, does not work for me. I apologize for not making that clear.